# Packaging Angular2 app with webpack. Bundle file does not work. The selector "my-app" did not match any elements

Tags: angular, webpack

I have very simple app in Angular2 that I would like to bundle into one js file.

I have following dir structure :

```
/-client
  |
  \-app
     - main.ts
     - app.module.ts
     - app.component.ts
     - app.component.spec.ts
  -webpack.config.js 
  - ....
```

config file looks as following :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
entry: {
'app': './app/main.ts'
  },

output: {
  filename: 'app.js'
},

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
},

module: {
  loaders: [
  {
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
  }

]
}

};
```

Build finish successfully and generates app.js (1.95MB) but when I import the file in the webpage I got following errors :

```
app.js:26914Error: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements
at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (http://localhost:3000/app.js:18516:23)
at DebugDomRenderer.selectRootElement (http://localhost:3000/app.js:37373:39)
at selectOrCreateRenderHostElement (http://localhost:3000/app.js:10870:32)
at DebugAppView.View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:13:16)
at DebugAppView.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/app.js:38774:21)
at DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/app.js:39034:52)
at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/app.js:17625:25)
at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (http://localhost:3000/app.js:16050:40)
at http://localhost:3000/app.js:15959:89
at Array.forEach (native)

zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Error in :0:0 caused by: The selector "my-app" did not match any elements ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value:
```

Any hints what I might be doing wrong?

thanks

m

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code. But it sounds like you either aren't defining the selector for `my-app` in `app.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
selector: 'my-app'
})
export class AppComponent {
...
```

and/or not bootstrapping that component in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      ...
    ],
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```